# Can anyone tell me why I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

This is my code below.

The error I get above will not move, I am trying lots of different variants.

```
var $token = $(this).attr('id');
var $itemId = $(this).find('input.id').val();
var $instaUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"'.$itemId.'"/likes?access_token="'.$token.'"';
console.log($instaUrl);
```

Thanks

Comment: The concatenation operator is `+`, not `.`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses `+` for string concatenation:

```
var $token = $(this).attr('id');
var $itemId = $(this).find('input.id').val();
var $instaUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"'+$itemId+'"/likes?access_token="'+$token+'"';
console.log($instaUrl);
```

You used the dot (`.`) from PHP.

By the way, you do not need to use a dollar sign for variables in JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` for concatenation in javascript.It can also be done using the following methods:

a. The addition operator ( `+` )

b. The assignment operator ( `+=` )

c. The built-in `concat` method

```
ar $token = $(this).attr('id');
var $itemId = $(this).find('input.id').val();
var $instaUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"'+$itemId+'"/likes?access_token="'+$token+'"';
console.log($instaUrl);
```